# Any function with domain $R\times R$ is a binary operation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the first assignment question for my UG Math course.

> ***Any function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$,  is a binary operation?***
> is this statement true or false? Give reasons for your answer in the form of a short proof or a counter example.

would the below reasoning be valid?

We are initially given a valid function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$ and an unknown co-domain. A binary operation on $\mathbb{R}$ defines a function from $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. While the domain of the given (valid) function is specified to be $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$, the co-domain is not explicitly specified to be $\mathbb{R}$ . Hence, generally, this statement is false for all complex valued functions of a real variable, as in: for the binary operation $a * b = +\sqrt {a + b}$ would result in complex values for, say $a=-1, b=-2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: see Wiki Operation: mathematics

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so as per that article "The values for which an operation is defined form a set called its domain" Does that imply that the sqrt counterexample which I gave does not qualify as a valid operation in the first place ? Meaning "any function with domain RxR is indeed a binary operation"  ? I am little confused about what should be assumed to be true and what should be deduced as implying, given the original statement.

Comment: I guess "any function with domain RxR.." does not imply or warrant the range to be R hence the statement that such a function is a binary operation is false.. sqrt operation was just a counterexample from my side.

Comment: The issue is that there is no “absolute” definition... if you allow the codomain to be different from the domain, a binary op is simply a function. If you assume that the domain is closed with respect to the op, like e.g. sum of numbers, then an op is a special case of function.

Comment: "square root" is not a function.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what about + "square root" from domain RxR to co-domain C ? Please note that the co-domain is really not specified to be R in the original statement.

Comment: Yes square root is an operation. My point of view is that “function” is defined rigorously: it has dom and codom and not necessarily the two are the same. Operation is more loosely defined: usually acts on objects of a domain that is closed with respect to the op. In a sense, complex numbers were “invented “ in order fo satisfy the closure prop of square root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics, an *operation* on a set $A$ is a function with domain contained in $A$, and with all values in $A$. Likewise, a *binary operation* on $A$ is a function with all values in $A$, but its domain contained in $A\times A$. Note that the domain doesn't have to be the whole of $A$ (or $A\times A$). For example, division is a binary operation on the natural numbers, even though though there are many pairs (e.g. $(2,3)$) for which division is not defined.

Thus, the statement in the question is false, and your counterexample demonstrates it. However, two points of clarification are needed. First, it is not clear whether $R$ is intended to refer to the real number set $\Bbb R$: generally, $R$ could represent any set. Second, your notation $a * b = +\sqrt {a + b}$ isn't defined for negative $a+b$ (and the initial plus sign doesn't help); perhaps you mean $a*b=\sqrt{a+b}$, for $a+b\geqslant0$, and $a*b=\sqrt{|a+b|}\,\mathrm i$ for $a+b<0$.

Comment: I just fixed the TeX for R above. This indeed is the set of real numbers, I confirm. The outer + (left of sqrt) is to consider only +ve values for the notation to qualify as a function and the inner + is sort of redundant; just that in-order to satisfy binary operation requirement I had to engage both a and b somehow. Since the co-domain is not specified in the question would this then become a valid function from RxR to C (complex numbers)  and therby serving as a counter example making the statement false ?

Comment: @n-mam : The initial plus sign doesn't change the fact that $\surd x$ is undefined when $x$ is negative. (I have clarified the answer to indicate that sign rather than the one between $a$ and $b$.) Yes, since the codomain is unspecified, you can choose any codomain you like (except a subset of $\Bbb R$!). An even simpler example would be the constant function $*:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ given by $a*b=\mathrm i$ for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: The initial + sign is there to satisfy the first condition of a well formed function viz that the mapping should be to only one element in the co-domain (since sqrt otherwise has 2 solutions).  √x is defined when x is negative if we consider the co-domain to be C. That way we have a function  from the given R×R to C and this I am hoping is an example of a function with domain RxR that is not a binary operation.

Comment: @n-mam : No, $\surd x$ is not defined when $x$ is negative. We can define $\surd x$ for positive $x$ because, of the two roots in $y$ of the equation $y^2=x$, we can select the positive one, and call it $\surd x$. But *positive* has no meaning off the real line.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to imply here.. of course I am aware that √x  is not defined when x is negative. My counter example (and your simplified version) is from R×R→C . Are you saying that even under this context it is wrong to consider √x  when x is negative ? what is the issue with -ve square root function when the co-domain/range in C ?

Comment: I updated my reasoning to highlight the counter-examples to be "complex valued functions of a real variable" i.e. from R×R→C . I'll mark this as the correct answer unless someone else come up with a different argument, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MathStackExchange.

A binary function is a function $f:A\times B\rightarrow C$ such that the domain $A\times B$ is a Cartesian product of two sets.

Binary means two-adic.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; a binary function is not the same as a binary operation.

Comment: Operation or function or mapping, its the same.

Comment: Not really; a [binary operation] on a set $R$ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) is a binary function $R \times R \to R$, while a binary function $R \times R \to C$ doesn't require $R$ and $C$ to be the same set.

Comment: I have made some edits in case it was not very clear the first time.  I believe @Rick is right in that the question specifically is asking if all functions with domain RxR would be equivalent to a binary operation.

Answer (score 0):

You gave an appropriate counter-example for how I believe the question should be interpreted.

I imagine that the goal of this problem is to emphasize the *on a set* aspect of the definition of a binary operation on a set. That is, a binary operation is a function $f:A\times A \to A$. Note that this maps an element of the cartesian product of a set with itself to the same set. The idea of a structure being closed under a binary operation is ubiquitous in algebra. (E.g. I'm guaranteed to get a rational number if I add two rational numbers).

Although binary operations are usually assumed to be closed on a set of interest, functions like scalar-vector multiplication and the vector cross-product are sometimes called binary operations even though they aren't generally on a set. Interestingly, the cross product is closed in $\mathbf{R}^3$ and $\mathbf{R}^7$.